# Handle a lot of controlled inputs with React

Tags: reactjs, forms, performance

I am creating a multiple choices quiz with React.

I have a huge form (variant size) that allow user to create questions and add choices to each of them.

This is the structure that I am working with.

```
<Form>
  <QuestionItem>
    <Question /> // input
    <Choices>
      <ChoiceItem /> // input
      <ChoiceItem /> // input
      <ChoiceItem /> // input
    </Choices>
  </QuestionItem>
  <QuestionItem> 
    <Question /> // input
    <Choices>
      <ChoiceItem /> // input
      <ChoiceItem /> // input
      <ChoiceItem /> // input
    </Choices>
  </QuestionItem>
</Form>
```

I would like to store all input values in a state, or a store.

But it seems to be slow when I type on those inputs if there .

What should I do to improve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

storing input values in store and dispatching action on every single change will definitely slow down your app but try storing values in state and change state on every change like so

```
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
this.state = {
    firstinputname: '',
    secondinputname: '',
    ...
}

handleChange(e){
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
}
```

and pass event handler and state value as prop to inputs like this

```
<Question onChange={onChange} value={this.state.fistinputname} />
```

and in your Qustion component:

```
<input type="yourinputtype" name="firstinputname" value={this.props.value} onChange={this.props.onChange}
```

Comment: We have a state of questions. And we use Array.map() to render all questions. And when we type question content or choice content in the input. All of components in this page will be re-render.
Imagine if we have 50 questions and when we have a small change and this page re-render. It is a big problem. So Do you have any idea to help me optimize this?

Comment: you can get the state inside input component and handle event inside it so only the child component is re-rendered. here check sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-goodall-h555w?fontsize=14